APS getScreenShotWithBounds with hidden elements in large models
I'm having good results using ScreenShot.getScreenShotWithBounds to get screen image from APS Viewer and overlay some annotations before rendering de .png file, both with 2d and 3d.
However, when the APS viewer has a large 3d model with hidden elements it seams that the function do not wait for all elements to be hidden before generating the screen shot. Some elements get hidden, others don't!
Any one else with this behavior? Any work around?

FYI: for 3d models, I have rolled back to legacy function (getScreenShotLegacy) with some adaptations, keeping getScreenShotWithBounds for 2d models, for automatic grey area removal. Solved for now
